# Smote Upsampling causing ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64'), but not finding any na's in data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

Trying to create a train/test set to run in a regression model, after performing a KMeans analysis on my dataset. When I'm using SMOTE to upsample, I get the following error:

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

The code I'm using is here:

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

# Upsampling using SMOTE
sm = SMOTE(random_state = random_state)
x_train_sm , y_train_sm = sm.fit_resample(x_train,y_train)

print("----------------------------")
print("Original x train shape, ", x_train.shape)
print("Resample x train shape, ", x_train_sm.shape)
```

At first, I thought there were na's in my dataset, even though I was pretty sure there weren't. So I checked and was showing 0 null values. That said, I went ahead and used this code to drop all na's, just in case.

```
df = df.dropna()
```

I still get the error. I'm not seeing any abnormally large values in the dataset either, not to mention, I've run MLR, Logistic, KNN and Decision Tree, no problem.

I'm at a loss of what's causing this. I even dropped all of my float64 columns just to see if one of those was causing it, still didn't work. Any ideas? My code is below:

```
ef Shuffle_data(df):
    """ Return shuffled data based on rows """
    return shuffle(df).reset_index().drop('index'
                                          , axis = 1)

def One_hot_encoding(df,feature):
    """ Apply one hot encoding to given features """
    return pd.concat([df
                      , pd.get_dummies(df[feature])]
                     , axis = 1)

def Merge_df(data, features):
    """ Return merge dataframe with given features"""
    merged_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for feature in features:
        merged_df = pd.concat([merged_df, data[feature]]
                              , axis = 1)
    return merged_df


def Normalize_df(data, cols):
    """ Normalize features """
    for col in cols:
        data[col] = Normalize_feature(data[[col]])
        
    return data    

def Create_model_df(df, col_cols, nom_cols, binary_cols, num_cols, target_col):
    """ Preparing data for modelling """
    
    df_model = Merge_df(df , [col_cols, num_cols, target_col])
    df_model = Shuffle_data(df_model)
    df_model = One_hot_encoding(df_model, nom_cols)
    
    df_model.drop(nom_cols, axis = 1, inplace = True)
    
    df_model = Normalize_df(df_model, num_cols)
    
    return (df_model.loc[:, ~df_model.columns.isin(target_col)]
            , df_model[target_col].values.flatten())


def Train_test_df(feature, target, test_size):
    """ Spliting data to train and test"""
    return train_test_split(feature
                     ,target
                     ,test_size= test_size
                     ,random_state= random_state)

from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score, GridSearchCV, cross_val_predict


df_model_feature ,df_model_target = Create_model_df(df_model
                                                    , cat_cols
                                                    , nominal_cols
                                                    , binary_cols
                                                    , num_cols
                                                    , [target_col])

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = Train_test_df(df_model_feature
                                                 , df_model_target
                                                 , test_size = 0.2)
```

Then I used the SMOTE code I posted at the beginning. I appreciate you help in either fixing this error or pointing me in the right direction in figuring out what is causing this.